# Pandas, groupby() function that separates out by "," but retains datatype?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to use the .groupby() function to consolidate repeating rows in a data frame, separate out non-similar elements by a ',', and have the resulting .groupby() data frame retain the original datatype of the non-similar elements / convert non-similar items to an object?

As I understand, a column in pandas can hold multiple datatypes, so I feel like this should be possible. 
 I can use the .agg() function to separate out non-similar elements by a ',', but it doesn't work with non-string elements.  I'd like to separate out the datatypes for error checking later when looking for rows with bad entries after the .groupby().

```
#Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Example dataframe
col = ['Acol', 'Bcol', 'Ccol', 'Dcol']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = col)
df['Acol'] = [1,1,2,3]
df['Bcol'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df['Ccol'] = [1,2,3,4]
df['Dcol'] = [1,'a',2,['a', 'b']]

#Code
outdf = df.groupby(by='Acol').agg(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
outdf
```

Comment: That is not possible, because the `join` function only works on string types. If you want to aggregate, you have to use `list`, so: `df.groupby(by='Acol').agg(list).reset_index()`

Comment: @Erfan.  Shoot. Okay, good to know.